# how to register for files of specific type in intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to write an intellij plugin that needs to have a file viewer of certain type/s.

say I have a bunch of .abc files in my project at various locations. I need my plugin to show a tree view of all those .abc files keeping their hierarchy intact.

what is the api I should look at ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plugin repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/) can [discover file types supported by a plugin](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/registering_file_type.html) and later IDE gets information about file types supported by different plugins. When you open a file of the file type supported by some plugin you get a notification in the IDE.

- [Registering a File Type](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/registering_file_type.html)

Comment: I want to show a tree view with the type of files I want to handle. If I have 100 of *.abc files, I want my tree to show those 100 files in the tree with the directory hierarchy intact. So, I need something like this.

Comment: You may ask a different question describing what you need and why with some real world example, my answer is exactly to this question: `how to register for files of specific type in intellij plugin`.

Comment: I want to show a tree view with the type of files I want to handle. If I have 100 of *.abc files, I want my tree to show those 100 files in the tree with the directory hierarchy intact. So, I need something like this.  project.getFilesOfExtension(".abc");  I found that project gives you its VirtualFile which you can navigate (children).  I could get the file name of a virtual file, but, I was looking for a 'get' method that gives me the project relative path (instead of the absolute path).

Comment: You can ask API related questions in the forum where the developers will answer them: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979